# How to get a set of records from within each partition based on a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

From a table like this:

| id | status | date | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PENDING | 2022-07-01 | XYZ |
| 2 | DONE | 2022-07-04 | XYZ |
| 3 | PENDING | 2022-07-03 | DEF |
| 4 | DONE | 2022-07-08 | DEF |

I would like to get the most recent records within each category (here 2 and 4). But there are at least two factors that complicate things.

First, there might be more than two records in the same category. (The records come in pairs.)

| id | status | date | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PENDING | 2022-07-01 | XYZ |
| 2 | PENDING | 2022-07-02 | XYZ |
| 3 | FAILED | 2022-07-04 | XYZ |
| 4 | FAILED | 2022-07-05 | XYZ |
| 5 | PENDING | 2022-07-03 | DEF |
| 6 | DONE | 2022-07-08 | DEF |

In this case, I'd have to get 3, 4, and 6. Were there six records in the XYZ category, I'd have to get the most recent three.

And, secondly, the date could be the same for the most recent records within a category.

I tried something like this:

```
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT *,
           dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY date DESC) rnk
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

But this fails when there are more than 2 records in a category and I need to get the most recent two.

**EDIT:**

Eli Johnson has pointed out in a comment that there should be information about which messages are pairs. Of course! I digged around a bit, and after a join or two there is.

| id | status | date | category | prev_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PENDING | 2022-07-01 | XYZ | `{}` |
| 2 | PENDING | 2022-07-02 | XYZ | `{}` |
| 3 | FAILED | 2022-07-04 | XYZ | `{1}` |
| 4 | FAILED | 2022-07-05 | XYZ | `{2}` |
| 5 | PENDING | 2022-07-03 | DEF | `{}` |
| 6 | DONE | 2022-07-08 | DEF | `{5}` |

Comment: In second table why do you want record with `id=3` for `XYZ`? Record with `id=4` is newer? :-?

Comment: (1, 3) and (2, 4) are pairs. Each pair refers to a different message belonging to the same category, and tracks the status of that message in time. Basically, what I want is to get the most recent status of each message in each category. In the second table, there are two messages in the category XYZ, and their most recent status is FAILED. I know this is a symptom of a bad design, but I've to work with it.

Comment: You are asking a question that relies upon knowing pairing info, but you haven't laid out any conditions that allow us to know which messages are paired.  Even if we assume (you haven't said) that status must change between two rows in the pair, how would we know that e.g. (1,4) and (2,3) are not the pairs?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, Eli! I added an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements are more hard-coded here then following proper design.
Based on what has been proposed in the question, I just tweaked it a little bit to get last records.

Assuming that records are always in pair, as mentioned in the question.

```
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT *,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY date1 DESC) rnk,
           count(1) over (partition by category) cnt
    FROM status
)
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE rnk*2 <= cnt;
```

Refer fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=218fd9ef3020dac01cb635e596608721).

Comment: Feel free to mark answer as accepted, if it was helpful.

Comment: Yes, it was very helpful. Thank you! Within the parameters set in the question originally, it works. I edited the question and added a bit more contextual information, where prev_id column can reveal pairs. I think it's possible to use that information to come up with a more robust solution. I'm working on that. Still I'm marking your answer as accepted.